# Compute $H^i(S,\underline{\text{Hom}}(A,\mathbb G_m))$ for a semi-abelian scheme $A$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

How can I compute $H^i(S,\underline{\text{Hom}}(A,\mathbb G_m))$ (where $A$ denotes a semi-abelian scheme over $S$, $\mathbb G_m$ denotes the multiplicative group over $S$ and $\underline{\text{Hom}}$ denotes the Hom sheaf)?

The base scheme can be assumed to be noetherian. Even the case of a dvr would be fine.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users and https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4249/unregistered-users-in-theory-and-in-practice

Comment: it's not related, I'm just new here!

Comment: (There is no problem as far as I can tell.)